# сравнение содержимого двух ArrayList<String> поэлементно

Tags: java, массивы, arraylist, сравнение

Необходимо сравнить массив, появившийся в результате работы программы, с массивом, существовавшим изначально.

Требуется сравнить их элементы, и если новый массив больше старого, или содержит новые элементы - необходимо выяснить, что это именно за элементы и вставить их в старый массив.

И наоборот, если новый массив стал меньше старого, необходимо выяснить каких элементов в нем не хватает, по сравнению с старым.

Comment: а какую цель приследуете, что в итоге хотите получить и для чего?

Comment: а почему просто не взять новый массив? так как вы и так делаете из старого копию нового.

Comment: @MikhailVaysman видимо, есть еще какой-то сокральный смысл в этом...

Comment: @LexHobbit дело в том, что есть консольное приложение, запускаемое из моей программы, в ответ на команду оно возвращает список букв подключенных флеш-накопителей, команду я отправляю в отдельном потоке каждую секунду, эти буквы сначала попадают в первый массив, а потом каждую секунду  во второй массив, и в зависимости от ответа, необходимо чтобы програма уведомляла пользователя об отключении флешки, либо о подключении новой, на основании сравнения этих двух массивов, добавляется/удаляется строка из ListBox, как то так если в кратце

Answer (score 0, accepted):

решил задачу следующим образом
у нас есть 2 массива, первый содержит в себе список подключенных флешек, например 1, 2, 3,
второй массив получаем от программы, он содержит 1, 2,
из первого масива удаляем 1, 2 - остается 3 - значит флешка 3 была отключена. и наоборот есть 2 массива, первый содержит в себе список подключенных флешек 1, 2, 3
второй массив получаем от программы 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
из второго массива удаляем значения 1, 2, 3. остается 4, 5 - значит флешки 4, 5 были подключены

```
    if (aLines.size() < bLines.size()){
                        bLines.removeAll(aLinesCopy);
                        aLines = bLines;
                        System.out.println("//уведомляем о подключении, флешек в bLines");
                    } else if (aLines.size() > bLines.size()){
                        aLinesCopy.removeAll(bLines);
                        aLines = bLines;
                        System.out.println("уведомляем что остаток из aLinesCopy был отключен от устройства");
                    }
```